# Replace uploaded document on confirm not working

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

*My Requirement is as follows:
When user uploads a file i should check for "**File already Exists**", if file exists i must show **confirm box if 'OK' i have to replace** and if cancel the reverse.
This is my following code*

```
if (file_exists($path . $documentName)) {
                $msg = $documentName . " already exists. ";
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var res = confirm('File already exists Do you want to replace?');
                    if (res == false) {
                <?php
                $msg = 'File Upload cancelled';
                ?>
                    } else {


                <?php
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"], $path . $documentName)) {
                    $msg = $documentName . " File Replaced Successfully";
                    $successURL = $document_path . $documentName;
                }
                else
                    $msg = $documentName . "Upload Failed";
                ?>
                    }
                </script>";
                <?
            }
```

My problem is even if i give cancel the file is getting replaced.
just let me know where I'm wrong or Is there any other approach?
Please help me to close this issue
Note:jquery Not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i came with with this following solution
upload

> ***uploaddocument.php***

```
            $documentName = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/s', '_', $_FILES["document"]["name"]);
            if (file_exists($path . $documentName)) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"], "F:\\Content\\enews_files\\temp\\" . $documentName);
                $msg = $documentName . " already exists. <a href='confirm.php?confirm=1&filename=" . $documentName . "&language=" . $lang . "'>Replace</a>||<a href='confirm.php?confirm=0&filename=" . $documentName . "'>Cancel</a>";
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"], $path . $documentName)) {
                    $msg = $documentName . " Upload Success";
                    $successURL = $document_path . $lang . '/' . $documentName;
                }
                else
                    $msg = $documentName . " Upload Failed";
            }
```

> ***confirm.php***

```
include("config_enews.php");
$lang = $_GET['language'];
$path = "F:\\Content\\enews_files\\" . $lang . "\\";
//$path = "D:\\test\\test\\" . $lang . "\\";
$documentName = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/s', '_', $_GET["filename"]);
if ($_GET['confirm'] == 1) {

//echo sys_get_temp_dir();die;
    if (copy("F:\\Content\\enews_files\\temp\\" . $_GET["filename"], $path . $documentName)) {
        unlink("F:\\Content\\enews_files\\temp\\" . $_GET["filename"]);
        header("Location: uploaddocument.php?message=success&fname=$documentName&lang=$lang");
    } else {
        echo $res = move_uploaded_file($_GET["tempname"], $path . $documentName);
        echo $msg = $documentName . " Upload Failed";
        header("Location: uploaddocument.php?message=failed&fname=$documentName");
    }
} else {
    unlink("F:\\Content\\enews_files\\temp\\" . $_GET["filename"]);
    header("Location: uploaddocument.php?message=cancelled&fname=$documentName");
}
```

I got this spark from @Marek. If any one has better solution kindly provide.

I don't have enough reputations to vote your answers sorry.

Thank you so much for all your support.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you mix javascript and PHP. The PHP-Code will be run on the server and generates the HTML-document. At this point, the file gets replaced already.

Then, this document (with the javascript-code inside) will then be send to the user and there the javascript-code is run. And in that moment, the user gets to see the confirmaion-dialog, even though the file already was replaced!

Take a look at the source-code that your php-code is generating and you will see what I mean.

A solution would be to add a checkbox to confirm overwriting files. Then after hitting the upload-/submit-button, your php-script would check if this box was checked and either replace the file or not.

Answer (score 2):

@Gogul, honestly, this is not the right way to go.  Better that you handle the file submission with an AJAX request which receives a response back from your server (either uploaded successfully, or file exists) which you handle appropriately.  If presenting the user an option to replace the file, again handle that action with AJAX.

You can do AJAX request in raw JavaScript (jQuery not required) - see here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing server side code with client side javascript. The solving of your problem is more complicated if you don't want the user to reupload the document:

1. Store the file in a temporary location under random filename. Output a yes/no form to the user, including the random filename and original filename.
2. If the user answers yes, move from temporary location to $path, else remove the file from temporary location.

Comment: So you are asking me use form alert?

Comment: Thanks now I got it. will complete it and post Back my answer